# Terminal in Ubuntu endlessly prints “>>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'” when attempting to install Anaconda

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, anaconda

When I start to install Anacoda on Ubuntu (running on a VirtualBox VM) with bash the terminal is stuck in printing:

> “>>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'”

[image: terminal output]

I have used `ls | xargs bash` to install the Anaconda.

- I have checked the installer with sha256 it's okay.
- I have installed Google Chrome and it has worked.
- I have installed an update to the system and an update to the bash itself by sudo apt-get update/upgrade.

What else might be wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] and post the *exact* command you used.

Comment: I have used ls | xargs bash to install the anaconda

Comment: `ls | xargs bash`? Is this the *exact* command? Why? It seems wrong on more than one level. `xargs bash` redirects stdin of `bash` to `/dev/null`, so whatever piece of code expects you to answer `yes` or `no`, it reads from `/dev/null`. No wonder it cannot get the right answer. I really don't know how you should install, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be with `ls | xargs bash`.

Comment: Okey thanks this is the case this is why it didn't work. I just have misunterstood what xargs command does now it works like a charm thank You very much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has been self-solved by the original poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a wrong usage of xargs command that was causing a terminal.
Thanks for Your help :)